# files property is undefined at file input (in jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input

```js
$('#files').change(function () {
    alert(`files : ${$(this).files}`);
    
    const selectedFilesName = [];
    for (const file of $(this).files) {
      selectedFilesName.push(`\n${file.name}`);
    }
    $('.output span').text(selectedFilesName);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" accept="image/*" multiple />
<pre class="output">selected files :<span></span></pre>
```

I wanted to get the information about the uploaded files in the file input. However, I could not do this using jQuery, but it was not a problem using JavaScript.

My question is how to do this with jQuery?

HTML codes:

[image]

JavaScript codes:

[image]

result (using JavaScript codes):

[image]

jQuery codes:

[image]

result (using jQuery codes):

[image: 2 files uploaded]
[image: in browser console, files is undefined!!!]

I used JavaScript and got the result correctly, but I'm having trouble with jQuery.

Comment: `fileInput` is a jquery object. But you want to access the native element which you can do with : `fileInput[0]`

Comment: `$` returns a jQuery-wrapped object. To access vanilla properties of the original element, use `$(selector)[0].files`, where `[0]` navigates to the element.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself, as [formatted text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212) and [**not** a picture](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4642212)_), along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.